# Simple javascript function not working on smaller devices Muse Adobe

Tags: javascript, muse

i needed to make an url validation so i added a script to the exported html to do so, it works like a charm. the problem is when i use a smaller screen (mobile or resized desktop browser) the script doesn't run at all. this happens when the browser screen is less than 960px.

Edit: I dont get any errors, if i call the function on the console it does the job but even doing an onkeypress call doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into that an hour ago and this is what i did and it solved the problem of externally loaded functions going away on screen resize.

```
1.right click on your page
2.choose page properties
3.choose metadata
4.add javascript in head section <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

ADDENDUM: Went fudding around the exported html and got a good leading hint/clue on what might be happenning. There is a musemanifest file whose root corresponds to the root file of the export. Then inside, there is a <> tag for every folder and it lists all files that are to be loaded by the require.js(suspicion i have). Let's start this thread and work the solution.